# Warning: sprintf()...too few arguments

Tags: php, printf

This is the line with the error

```
sprintf( __( "You must have a <a target='_new' href='%s'>PayPal Sandbox</a> account setup before using this feature.", APP_TD ), 'http://developer.paypal.com/' ),
```

Comment: That doesn't look right. Please post the entire line.

Comment: You need to debug what Wordpress' `__()` function is returning.

Answer (score 1):

```
sprintf( __( 'You must have a <a target="_new" href="%s">PayPal Sandbox</a> account setup before using this feature.', APP_TD ), 'http://developer.paypal.com/' ),
```

Might be your usage of single/double quotes.